# Regular Expressions in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

Ok so I need a regex for any co-ordinate in the form x,y  where x and y are single digits from 1 to 9

I tried this:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "[1-9],[1-9]")
```

but this allows values such as "11,99" when I can only allow single integers from 1-9 on each side of the comma.

Please, help. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If a question usefully answers one of your questions we ask that you click the accept checkmark next to the question so that other people can come back later and more easily scan the answers for useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches the expression because `IsMatch` returns `true` if the string contains at least one match for the given regular expression. If you need to be sure that the whole string matches the given expression you should rewrite it as follow:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "^[1-9],[1-9]$")
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `\b` be a bit more accurate? That way it doesn't have to be the whole line...

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl at first I wrote \b but actually in the question is not clear if it's a list of coordinates (so \b may be appropriate) or a single pair, anyway now he knows it's an option...

Answer (score 0):

```
If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), "^[1-9],[1-9]$")
```

Note the added `Trim()` to prevent whitespace causing problems.

Comment: It'll match, for example, even this: ",111"

Comment: If you’re using regular expressions already then `Trim` is redundant, just allow spaces at the start and end of the expression.

Comment: @KonradRudolph , if allowing whitespaces, then it would be ^[\b]*[1-9],[1-9][\b]*$  or? So that would be the solution, instead of using .Trim?

Comment: @Amegon Too complicated, no need for the character classes; and `\b` isn’t the right class anyway. Use `^\s*\d,\d\s*$`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it allows repeating? I thought a + or a * needs to be added afterwards in order to allow multiple occurrences. What you are looking for, is a rule before that, to define that it is the beginning of the string, and at the end the end of the string

Comment: It doesn't allow repeating, but it would match on 11,99. It matches the 1,9 part and 'ignores' the 1 at the start and 9 at the end. You need ^ and $ to tell the regex engine that you want to match the whole string

Comment: Yep, just didn't want to say it so direct, but you are right :) 1 **1,9** 9 -> Match

Comment: Ah, I see. You were giving a teachers answer, carefully pushing the questioner toward figuring it out themselves, and then on to greater learning and enlightenment :D I didn't read much beyond the first line, sorry!

Comment: Hoping to do it that way, yeah, and because I made some -1 'friends' when answering too direct. Thanks for understanding :)